# PHP foreach and returning unique headers from table rows

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

What I want to happen is... I know that an *if* goes in the the foreach but I cannot seem to get to work. Please help me.

**GDESCRIP**
code, descrip
code, descrip
code, descrip
**GDESCRIP**
code, descrip
code, descrip
code, descrip

```
$query = "Select gdescrip, code, descrip from sometable group by gdescrip  order by code";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {
            $rows[$row['gdescrip']][] = $row['code'];
        }
    foreach($rows as $key => $category)
        echo '<strong>' .$key. '</strong><br />';
    foreach($category as $item)
        {
            echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$item.'">' . $item .' </input><br/>';
        }
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: You're not putting `$row['descrip'] in `$rows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not putting `$row['descrip']` into `$rows`. The simplest way to do that is to add another dimension to `$rows`, and put the whole row returned from the query into that dimension.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $rows[$row['gdescrip'][] = $row;
}
```

The second `foreach` loop needs to be nested inside the first one.

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $category) {
    echo "<strong>$key</strong><br/>";
    foreach ($category as $item) {
        echo "<input type='radio' name='{$item['code']}'>{$item['code']} {$item['descrip']}<br/>";
    }
}
```

And there's no such thing as `</input>`; `<input>` is self-closing, it doesn't contain other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was able to get working. Obviously it is not mysqli but apparently I just don't know enough about mysqli to change this script so that it does work.  Someone please feel free to point out where I am missing the mysqli conversion. Thank you in advance for your knowledge.

```
$categories = array();
$result = select statement;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $categories[$row['gdescrip']][] = $row;
}
foreach($categories as $key => $category){
echo '<strong>' .$key. '</strong><br/>';
foreach($category as $item){ 
    $key = str_replace(' ',"_",$key);
    echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$item['code'].'">' .$item['code'] . $item['DESCRIP'] .  '<br/>';
 }
}
```